# Evaluation my CNN stopped with message "OOM when allocating tensor with shape[3,3,256,512]"

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, evaluation

I build a CNN with 5 layers, 100 epoch, 32 batch size and trained it with tensorflow-gpu on device with 16gb ram, 4gb nvidia GTX card with 5 cuda compute capability. the training process was done successfully and fast with 80% of training data. My problem result when I want to evaluate the remaining 20% unseen data of images on the same network. Evaluation process go very slowly and stop with message:

```
    ResourceExhaustedError (see above for traceback): OOM when allocating tensor with shape[3,3,256,512] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
 [[Node: conv2d_5_122/kernel/Assign = Assign[T=DT_FLOAT, use_locking=true, validate_shape=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](conv2d_5_122/kernel, conv2d_5_122/random_uniform)]]
    Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.
```

Can anyone please please help me, I'm confusing. Thanks.

Comment: Your GPU doesn't seem to have enough memory to run that job

Comment: @DroidX86 Thank you for your reply. My GPU is 4 gb it worked good with training data which are 80% of dataset, while evaluation data are 20% of dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem while evaluating [Open L3 CNN](https://www.justinsalamon.com/news/openl3-competitive-open-deep-audio-embedding) for creating embeddings of audio data.

I found out that I was loading the model repeatedly in a loop when I called the `model.test()` function. In my case the test function was:
`openl3.get_audio_embedding(audio, sampling_rate)`

When I reloaded the model again and again from the disk, it exhausted the memory.

So, the solution is to load the model once, as in my case I loaded the openl3 model:

`model = openl3.models.load_audio_embedding_model(input_repr="mel256", content_type="music",embedding_size=615)`

and then processed the test data with the model, as in my case I did:

`loop starts:`

`openl3.get_audio_embedding(audio, sampling_rate, **model**)`

`loop ends`

So, check if you are reloading the model while processing each test sample.